# How to find all parameteres of a class and their type?

Tags: java, reflection

I want to write a java program to print all (public or private) parameters of a class and their types. I think I have to use *reflection*, but I'm noob at java reflection.

As an example, I need the my program to run on below class and result in following output:

```
class a{
    public int b;
    public int c;
    private String s;    
}
```

output:

```
b: int
c: int
s: St
```

Finally my question is how to get a list of parameters of a class and their types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend you explore the javadoc, starting with the [`Class`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class:

> Instances of the class `Class` represent classes and interfaces in a running Java application.

Of note is the method `getDeclaredFields()`, which returns an array of [`Field`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) objects representing the fields the class declares.

Also take note of the ways to obtain a `Class` object:

```
Class<MyClass> c = MyClass.class; //statically

MyClass mc = new MyClass();
Class<? extends MyClass> c2 = mc.getClass(); //dynamically
```

Answer (score 3):

```
try {
    Class c = Class.forName("a");

    Field[] fs = c.getDeclaredFields();

    for(Field f : fs){
        System.out.println(f.getName()+": "+f.getType().getSimpleName());
    }

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
```